# What is known about societal mental degradation?

Tags: experimental-psychology, mental-exhaustion, group

Question comes to me after reading about Calhoun's [Universe 25](https://www.the-scientist.com/foundations/universe-25-1968-1973-69941#:%7E:text=UNIVERSE%2025%3A%20John%20Calhoun%20crouches,termed%20a%20%E2%80%9Cbehavioral%20sink.%E2%80%9D) experiment, where mental degradation of mice was observed under extreme overcrowding.

What interested me here how the mental state of the whole group of mice degraded together. Are there examples of such societal mental degradations in humans? What general insights does psychology give us?

Comment: There is a [reverse Flynn effect](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338633042_THE_REVERSAL_OF_THE_FLYNN_EFFECT_2020) - is this what you had in mind?